# Bevelling concave curve part results in buggy mesh

Tags: bezier-curves, extrude

I want to create some extruded, bevelled letters, and thus have created letters with the Font tool, then converted them to curves.

I have an issue with the letter B, which creates a buggy mesh surface near a concave curve point (selected here).
[image]

As soon as I bevel this object a little, the curve part starts to get modelled badly:
[image]

There's indeed only one curve vertex, not multiple at the same spot (I thought that might have been the problem). I don't find a way to easily fix this; the bevel should of course not create such a weirdly sticking-out part.

Did I miss a bevel option? Do I have to set sharp edges or something?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are seeing are shading artifacts from intersecting geometry.

Very tight sharp corners always cause problems when beveling in graphics software in general, since the software can't automatically handle these hard corner-cases cases unless it is specifically programmed to, or an option exists to clip/trim or extend said bevel options.

Blender has no special tools to deal with these so they end up self intersecting.

I usually solve it with the *Offset* modification available to the left of *Bevel* value.

Since beveling offsets the curve "outside" by the same amount of units used as bevel factor, all you have to do is counter this by using that value as a negative factor for offset so Blender "insets" the growth.

[image]

Additionally you may want to add an *Edge Split* modifier to your curve to avoid smoothing artifacts or errors.

Comment: I tried that, and while it gets rid of the "bug", it makes the letters a lot "thinner"... is there any way around that? I wish I could have them in the thickness they had before applying the offset.

Comment: In that case I would advise to use a font that originally has the correct thickness or desired text weigh before modification, so that when you bevel it you can still correct the weight increase get the desired final shape you want after bevel correction. Alternatively if you drew each character by hand draw them with the correct final weight and look you are aiming for so once again you can compensate for bevel and still get the desired shape.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that would be the only correct solution to use a better font. I just had the task to remaster a very old game logo, given a set font, and somehow he made the bevel look unbugged, but he used different tools though back then. Anyway, eventually I fixed that bevel of the B manually, as it was the only bug in the end. =)