# Extrude and Bevel problems with SVG Curves

Tags: bezier-curves, import, edges, bevel, artifacts

Alright, so I'm working on a background using a 2D logo I've created for myself in Illustrator. Ive decided that for starters, I want to turn the logo into a 3D object, with each path beveled on the sides. I can import/ extrude the .svg no problem, but when I reach the beveling part, I come across two problems; the curves corners get stretched out of proportion increase the bevel to where I want it to be, and the bevel itself has artifacts in those same areas. Here are screenshots before and after beveling:

[image: logo pre-bevel]
[image: logo post-bevel]

Is there a way to make the bevel dig into the model itself, rather than add more volume to the curve? Also, is there any other way to clean up the corner artifacts aside from manually?

Comment: you need to work on the sharp angles individually, edit the radius.

Comment: related: [extrude and bevel an imported svg curve](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47217/extrude-and-bevel-an-imported-svg-curve)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extrude and bevel an imported svg curve](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47217/extrude-and-bevel-an-imported-svg-curve)

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51327/bevelling-concave-curve-part-results-in-buggy-mesh/