# How to SVG Extrude, Remesh and Beveling letter correctly?

Tags: bevel

I am new to Blender and I wanted to take a SVG file and turn it into an object/mesh with a medium sized bevel only on the top.

First, I began with importing the SVG file into Blender and using the Object Data Properties tab to adjust the extrude and bevel. At first, I thought this worked but then I learned that the bevel is intersecting with itself creating an artifact and it has poor topology.

[image]

After this I decided to create a mesh from the SVG, apply a solidify modifier, and attempt to bevel. This worked fine for some characters, but them I came to another realization that the bevels were inconsistent, and some letters bevel more than others.

[image]

I added a remesh modifier in attempt to create a better topology for the letters. I do not know if this helped because the situation was  the same (I cannot bevel as much as I want to). I've tried things such as removing double vertices (merge distance), make manifold, but it seems like these make it worse or have no affect.

[image]

If anyone could guide me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated!!

Edit: I also understand that unchecking clamp overlap will let me bevel more, but this result brings more issues

Comment: After you convert your SVG to mesh, use  a _Decimate Modifier_ set to _Planar_  (or even do it after you extrude) and apply it. It does a lot to clean up the dirty geometry that often comes with SVG's. After that, you'll have a much better chance at a clean bevel (although it does not necessarily work in _all_ cases - it depends largely on the original topology).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried this but I am still left with the same result. The bevels are still very very tiny.

Comment: Well.... a couple of more things you can try - make sure your normals are all facing the right way (select the whole thing in edit mode then pick `mesh > normals > recalculate outside` from the menu at the top). Also make sure you have a uniform scale by applying it (`Ctrl+A > Scale`  in object mode).

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51327/bevelling-concave-curve-part-results-in-buggy-mesh/51328#51328